# Is it possible to combine these two SQL statements into one?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using these two MySQL statements to get all messages between two users, but I am running into a pretty big problem when it comes to manipulating the data later in the code since it's not in order by ID. Is there any way to combine these statements AND order the results by ID?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender='" . $username . "' AND receiver='" . $chatPartner . "'"

$sqlTwo = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender='" . $chatPartner . "' AND receiver='" . $username . "'"
```

Essentially, I need every occurrence of a message between two people, but sorted by ID. As of right now, I am joining the arrays to get my full list, but it's not in order by ID.

Comment: Yes, you can use `or` with parentheses...

Comment: Sometimes ORs can be slow, if you find that is the case, try a union all.

Comment: Not only that, but it's also very prone to SQL Injections! Do not string-concatenate sql queries! There's better ways like http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE (sender='" . $username . "' AND receiver='" . $chatPartner . "'")
OR (sender='" . $chatPartner . "' AND receiver='" . $username . "'")
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just combine both into 1 query ?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (sender=" . $username . " OR sender =". $chatPartner .") AND (receiver=" . $chatPartner . " OR receiver=" . $username .") ORDER BY id"
```

Comment: It did not work. I was returned with the error: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a shorter version of @dtj's answer using [row constructors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/row-subqueries.html).

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE (sender, receiver) IN (($username, $chatPartner),($chatPartner, $username))
ORDER BY id DESC
```

In my opinion it looks a bit nicer in code and makes it more readable, but remember that it doesn't improve performance of execution.